# Gradle creates circular dependency on multi-module project - Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have the following configuration on projects:

```
TopProject
|
|-ProjectA
|    |-SubProjectAA
|    |    -build.gradle
|    |-SubProjectAB
|    |    -build.gradle
|    |-build.gradle
|    --settings.gradle
--ProjectB
     |-SubProjectBA
     |    -build.gradle
     |-SubProjectBB
     |    -build.gradle
     |-build.gradle
     --settings.gradle
```

SubProjectBA depends on SubProjectBB, and all the subprojects on projectA depend on SubProjectBA.

Everything seems to be working fine except when Gradle is recompiled. Then it creates a circular dependency between BA and BB.

There is no imports from BB to BA, not explicit requirement to compile it like that.
I have the suspicion that it may be that project A configuration is the problem.
The setting from projectA

```
rootProject.name = 'projectA'
include 'SubProjectAA'
include 'SubProjectAB'

include ':SubProjectBA',':SubProjectBB'
project(':SubProjectBA').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../projectB/SubProjectBA')
project(':SubProjectBB').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../projectB/SubProjectBB')
```

and in build.gradle of projectA

```
 dependencies{
    compile project (':SubProjectBA')
}
```

Worst case escenario is there a way to enforce SubProjectBB to compile SubProjectBA?

Comment: Just to add, I am using Intellij Idea 14

Comment: Did you try with the current version?

Comment: Yes, same result 2017.1.4.

Comment: Gradle 4.0  too.

Comment: I think I need to enforce that BB is provided to BA in runtime.